# Can I have NodeJS and Apache in the same server?

Tags: apache, express, web, server

My boss gave me an Apache server and I need to upload files there through a web site that I'm developing, I'm using Angular 7 Cli for the frontend and NodeJS Express for the backend. I can recive all the files into my NodeJS server using "multer" but Node saves them into my computer. Is there any way to connect my Node Server to the Apache server, because I don't want to have a local server. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the point of the Apache server?  What is it being used for?  Why do you want to connect your nodejs server to your Apache server.   We can't really help with solutions without understanding why you even have an Apache server and what it's being used for.  Your nodejs server can handle your whole web-site.  If you don't want it on your local computer, then put the nodejs server code on a real server and run it there.

Comment: You need to have  a VPS , that you can connect directly and install the necessary tools (like nodejs , angular-cli , npm etc ..) and deploy your whole app into thi server !